# How to transpose/convert rows as columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table structures  like below
**Subjects Table**

```
      +----+------+------+--------+---------+
      | id | C_Id | G_Id | status | subject |
      +----+------+------+--------+---------+
      |  1 |   13 |    4 |      1 | Telugu  |
      |  2 |   13 |    4 |      1 | Hindi   |
      |  3 |   13 |    4 |      1 | English |
      |  4 |   13 |    4 |      1 | Maths   |
      |  5 |   13 |    4 |      1 | Physics |
      |  6 |   13 |    4 |      1 | Biology |
      |  7 |   13 |    4 |      1 | Social  |
      +----+------+------+--------+---------+ 

      +----+-----+-----+--------+--------+-------+-------+-------+
      | id | Cid | Gid | Examid | rollno | subId | Marks | paper |
      +----+-----+-----+--------+--------+-------+-------+-------+
      |  1 |  13 |   4 |      1 |      1 |     1 | 14.50 |     1 |
      |  2 |  13 |   4 |      1 |      2 |     1 | 12.00 |     1 |
      |  3 |  13 |   4 |      1 |      1 |     2 | 13.00 |     1 |
      |  4 |  13 |   4 |      1 |      2 |     2 | 15.00 |     1 |
      |  5 |  13 |   4 |      1 |      1 |     3 | 16.00 |     1 |
      |  6 |  13 |   4 |      1 |      2 |     3 | 18.00 |     1 |
      |  7 |  13 |   4 |      1 |      1 |     4 | 19.00 |     1 |
      |  8 |  13 |   4 |      1 |      2 |     4 | 23.00 |     1 |
      |  9 |  13 |   4 |      1 |      1 |     5 | 21.00 |     1 |
      | 10 |  13 |   4 |      1 |      2 |     5 | 24.00 |     1 |
      | 11 |  13 |   4 |      1 |      1 |     6 | 20.00 |     1 |
      | 12 |  13 |   4 |      1 |      2 |     6 | 19.00 |     1 |
      | 13 |  13 |   4 |      1 |      1 |     7 | 20.00 |     1 |
      | 14 |  13 |   4 |      1 |      2 |     7 | 21.00 |     1 |
      | 15 |  13 |   4 |      2 |      1 |     1 | 45.00 |     2 |
      | 16 |  13 |   4 |      2 |      2 |     1 | 40.00 |     2 |
      | 17 |  13 |   4 |      2 |      1 |     1 | 32.00 |     3 |
      | 18 |  13 |   4 |      2 |      2 |     1 | 33.00 |     3 |
      | 19 |  13 |   4 |      2 |      1 |     2 | 80.00 |     1 |
      | 20 |  13 |   4 |      2 |      2 |     2 | 89.00 |     1 |
      | 21 |  13 |   4 |      2 |      1 |     3 | 39.00 |     2 |
      | 22 |  13 |   4 |      2 |      2 |     3 | 38.00 |     2 |
      | 23 |  13 |   4 |      2 |      1 |     3 | 41.00 |     3 |
      | 24 |  13 |   4 |      2 |      2 |     3 | 45.00 |     3 |
      | 25 |  13 |   4 |      2 |      1 |     4 | 34.00 |     2 |
      | 26 |  13 |   4 |      2 |      2 |     4 | 38.00 |     2 |
      | 27 |  13 |   4 |      2 |      1 |     4 | 32.00 |     3 |
      | 28 |  13 |   4 |      2 |      2 |     4 | 33.00 |     3 |
      | 29 |  13 |   4 |      2 |      1 |     5 | 31.00 |     1 |
      | 30 |  13 |   4 |      2 |      2 |     5 | 34.00 |     1 |
      | 31 |  13 |   4 |      2 |      1 |     6 | 33.00 |     1 |
      | 32 |  13 |   4 |      2 |      2 |     6 | 31.00 |     1 |
      | 33 |  13 |   4 |      2 |      1 |     7 | 35.00 |     2 |
      | 34 |  13 |   4 |      2 |      2 |     7 | 31.00 |     2 |
      | 35 |  13 |   4 |      2 |      1 |     7 | 43.00 |     3 |
      | 36 |  13 |   4 |      2 |      2 |     7 | 38.00 |     3 |
      +----+-----+-----+--------+--------+-------+-------+-------+
```

So Far I have wrote the code

```
select ta.rollno,
ta.StdNm,
max(case when s.subject = 'Telugu' AND tm.paper=1 then tm.Marks end) Telugu,
max(case when s.subject = 'Telugu' AND tm.paper=2 then tm.Marks end) Telugu1,
max(case when s.subject = 'Telugu' AND tm.paper=3 then tm.Marks end) Telugu2,
max(case when s.subject = 'Hindi' AND tm.paper=1 then tm.Marks end) Hindi,
max(case when s.subject = 'Hindi' AND tm.paper=2 then tm.Marks end) Hindi1,
max(case when s.subject = 'Hindi' AND tm.paper=3 then tm.Marks end) Hindi2,
max(case when s.subject = 'English' AND tm.paper=1 then tm.Marks end) English,
max(case when s.subject = 'English' AND tm.paper=2 then tm.Marks end) English1,
max(case when s.subject = 'English' AND tm.paper=3 then tm.Marks end) English2,
max(case when s.subject = 'Maths' AND tm.paper=1 then tm.Marks end) Maths,
max(case when s.subject = 'Maths' AND tm.paper=2 then tm.Marks end) Maths1,
max(case when s.subject = 'Maths' AND tm.paper=3 then tm.Marks end) Maths2,
max(case when s.subject = 'Physics' AND tm.paper=1 then tm.Marks end) Physics,
max(case when s.subject = 'Physics' AND tm.paper=2 then tm.Marks end) Physics1,
max(case when s.subject = 'Physics' AND tm.paper=3 then tm.Marks end) Physics2,
max(case when s.subject = 'Biology' AND tm.paper=1 then tm.Marks end) Biology,
max(case when s.subject = 'Biology' AND tm.paper=2 then tm.Marks end) Biology1,
max(case when s.subject = 'Biology' AND tm.paper=3 then tm.Marks end) Biology2,
max(case when s.subject = 'Social' AND tm.paper=1 then tm.Marks end) Social,
max(case when s.subject = 'Social' AND tm.paper=2 then tm.Marks end) Social1,
max(case when s.subject = 'Social' AND tm.paper=3 then tm.Marks end) Social2
FROM tbl_cmarks tm
INNER JOIN tbl_classes tc
 ON tm.Cid = tc.C_Id
INNER JOIN tbl_admission ta
 ON ta.rollno = tm.rollno
INNER JOIN tbl_subjects s
 on tm.subId = s.id
where tm.Cid = 13 
and tm.Examid=2
group by  ta.rollno
```

Here in my script i am passing the subjects Names as hard Coded But in future we don't know how many subjects will have in Class 13 
where should i change in my query to pass the subject Ids instead of Subject Names and that too not as hard coded.

Can i take all subject Ids for Particular Class into a variable and pass in the Max(Case) statement.? Is it possible?

Please  review my code and give me a clue/help, to do work this code.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to do that you have to use dynamic SQL.

To simplify things on the client side it's better to wrap it in a stored procedure.
In your case such procedure might look like

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_exam(IN _cid INT, IN _examid INT)
BEGIN
    SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = (7 * 1024);

    SET @sql = NULL;

    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
             CONCAT(
               'MAX(CASE WHEN m.subid = ', subid,
               ' AND m.paper = ', paper, 
               ' THEN m.marks END) ', subject, paper))
      INTO @sql
      FROM tbl_cmarks m JOIN tbl_subjects s 
        ON m.subid = s.id
     WHERE cid = _cid
       AND examid = _examid;

    SET @sql = CONCAT(
                 'SELECT a.rollno, a.stdnm, ', @sql,  
                  ' FROM tbl_cmarks m JOIN tbl_admission a
                      ON m.rollno = a.rollno 
                   WHERE m.cid = ', _cid, 
                   ' AND m.examid = ', _examid,
                 ' GROUP BY a.rollno, a.stdnm');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Note:** JOINs with `tbl_classes` and `tbl_subjects` have been removed since you don't fetch anything from the former and you don't need later for conditional grouping (ids used instead).

Then on client side you just do

```
CALL sp_exam(13, 2);
```

Sample output:

```
| ROLLNO |     STDNM | TELUGU2 | TELUGU3 | HINDI1 | ENGLISH2 | ENGLISH3 | MATHS2 | MATHS3 | PHYSICS1 | BIOLOGY1 | SOCIAL2 | SOCIAL3 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      1 | Student 1 |      45 |      32 |     80 |       39 |       41 |     34 |     32 |       31 |       33 |      35 |      43 |
|      2 | Student 2 |      40 |      33 |     89 |       38 |       45 |     38 |     33 |       34 |       31 |      31 |      38 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25333/1)** demo